# What will be the value given for oauth_url, success_url, menu_url in config file of consolibyte QuickBooks PHP DevKit

Tags: quickbooks

I have download the consolibyte QuickBooks PHP DevKit & set `$token`, `$oauth_consumer_key`, `$oauth_consumer_secret key` in config file. I have doubt in `$quickbooks_oauth_url`. Is it

```
$quickbooks_oauth_url = 'https://appcenter.intuit.com/Playground/OAuth/IA/?ck='.$oauth_consumer_key.'&cs='.$oauth_consumer_secret;
```

Also have doubt in `$quickbooks_success_url` (Is it my app site address) & `$quickbooks_menu_url`. Please give me answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the `config.php` file example here:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/tree/master/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3

You'll notice that:

- the oauth URL is set to `http://(your HTTP path here)/oauth.php`

And that in that same directory, there's an `oauth.php` script already provided for you.

- you should point the `$quickbooks_oauth_url` to that `oauth.php` script.

Similarly, you'll notice that:

- the success URL is set to `http://(your HTTP path here)/success.php`

And again in that directory there's a `success.php` script already provided for you.

- you should point the `$quickbooks_success_url` to that `success.php` script.

I'm willing to bet you can guess what I'm going to say about `$quickbooks_menu_url`, can't you?  (hint - there's a `menu.php` script already provided for you in the same directory... point `$quickbooks_menu_url` to the `menu.php` script...)